# Row with an Operation of three subqueries - Mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, operation

I am trying to make a query with 3 fields, one of them is the type of a product, another is today's date and another is a calculation of two tables, the problem I have is with the calculation of the two tables.

I can not show all the records because this calculation shows several records and therefore the query gives an error: "Operand should contain 1 column" so if I put a limit 1 to these queries it works fine, but only shows a record and I want that shows all that exist.

To do what I need depends on three tables:

- Table Orders:
  id, fecha_entrega, unidades, id_formatopeso ...
  translate:
  id, date_delivery, units, id_weightformat
- Table weight format:
  id_formatopeso, tipo_formato, stock_minimo ...
  translate:
  id_weightformat, format_type, minimum_stock
- Table Stock:
  id_stock, stock_pizza, fecha, id_formatopeso
  translate:
  id_stock, stock_pizza, date, id_weightformat
  I need an operation that calculates:

The query add subquery is:

1. The `units` of the `orders` table with today's delivery date of each product (weight format)
2. Subtract
   The `stock_pizza` of the last record in the `stock` table of each product (weight format)
3. Sum
   The `stock_minimo` that each product has (weight format)

Table Pedidos(Orders):

```
+----------------+---------------+----------+----------------+
| id_formatopeso | fecha_entrega | unidades | id_formatopeso |
+----------------+---------------+----------+----------------+
|              2 | 2017-10-25    |       50 |              2 |
|              7 | 2017-11-09    |      450 |              7 |
|              6 | 2017-11-09    |      500 |              6 |
+----------------+---------------+----------+----------------+
```

Tabla Formatopeso(Weight format)

```
+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| id_formatopeso | tipo_formato | stock_minimo |
+----------------+--------------+--------------+
|              2 | 12Ø 70gr     |          150 |
|              7 | 20Ø 150gr    |          150 |
|              6 | 22Ø 180gr    |          150 |
+----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Tabla Stock

```
+----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
| id_stock | stock_pizza | fecha      | id_formatopeso |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
|        2 |          50 | 2017-10-25 |              2 |
|        7 |         200 | 2017-11-09 |              7 |
|        6 |         300 | 2017-11-09 |              6 |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
```

Pedidos tipo_formato: 20Ø 150gr id=7;
450(unidades table orders) – 200(stock_pizza table stock) + 150 (minimum_stock table stock) = 400(Pizza_calculo)

Pedidos tipo_formato: 22Ø 180gr id=6;
500(unidades table Orders) – 300(stock_pizza table stock) + 150(minimum_stock table stock) = 350(Pizza_calculo)

I need show something like this:

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| format_type  |pizza_operation|  date_today |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| tipo_formato | pizza_calculo |  fecha_hoy  |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| 20Ø 150gr    |           400 |  2017-11-09 |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| 22Ø 180gr    |           350 |  2017-11-09 |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+
```

My query not working:

```
SELECT formatopeso.tipo_formato, 
   (SELECT unidades FROM pedidos WHERE DATE(fecha_entrega) = DATE(NOW())) 
   -
   (SELECT stock_pizza FROM stock WHERE fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) FROM stock)LIMIT 1)
   +
   (SELECT stock_minimo FROM formatopeso LIMIT 1)
   as pizza_calculo, 
   (SELECT CURDATE())
   as fecha_hoy
FROM pedidos
INNER JOIN formatopeso
ON formatopeso.id_formatopeso = pedidos.id_formatopeso
WHERE pedidos.fecha_entrega IN (CURDATE())
GROUP BY formatopeso.tipo_formato;
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do without seeing the tables that you're getting the data from.

Comment: Also add an explanation of the relationships between the tables, and what the query is supposed to do. It's hard to understand from the query since the names aren't in English.

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar, for fixing the post and I apologize for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: It would still help to show the original data, your explanations don't help very much.

Comment: Excuse me, I have already modified the post with all the necessary information to understand what I would like to do, thanks again.

Comment: You added that after my comment.

Comment: I have added the rest of the information to understand what I need, could you help me then, or what else do you need to understand my problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be joining the tables, not using subqueries in `SELECT`. Use the technique in [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1) to get the most recent record in the `stock` table for each product.

```
SELECT f.tipo_formato, p.unidades - s1.stock_pizza + f.stock_minimo AS pizza_calculo, p.fecha_entrega AS date_today
FROM pedidos AS p
JOIN formatopeso AS f ON f.id_formatopeso = p.id_formatopeso
JOIN stock AS s1 ON s1.id_formatopeso = p.id_formatopeso
JOIN (SELECT id_formatopeso, MAX(fecha) AS max_fecha
      FROM stock
      GROUP BY id_formatopeso) AS s2
    ON s1.id_formatopeso = s2.id_formatopeso AND s1.fecha = s2.max_fecha
WHERE p.fecha_entrega = CURDATE()
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30a50e/1)

Comment: You don't know how much I appreciate your help Barman, you've been a teacher teaching how to understand a complex query (for me) I appreciate your interest and I'm sorry when I created the post in an incorrect way.

It works perfectly and thanks also for putting a demo.